# mysql get rows in one table with date in another table for one year but not another

Tags: mysql, select

I can't find a reply on here that deals with my type of problem, but if there is I apologize in advance.

I have 2 tables : clients & orders.

I need to be able to select all clients that have at least one order in 2015, but no order in 2016.

I can get any client that has an order in 2015 by doing

```
SELECT * 
  FROM clients AS t1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN orders AS t2 
    ON t2.clientid=t1.clientid 
 WHERE t2.orderdate>='2015-01-01' 
   AND t2.orderdate<='2015-12-31' 
 GROUP 
    BY t1.clientid
```

but how can I change this so that it eliminates any clients that also have an order in 2016?

thanks

Comment: Note that this presently renders as an inner join. And, performance benfits aside, in the absence of any aggregatinf functions, don't use GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a not in with a subselect  excluding the id fo the client in 2016

```
SELECT * 
  FROM clients AS t1 
  INNER 
  JOIN orders AS t2 
    ON t2.clientid=t1.clientid 
 WHERE t2.orderdate>='2015-01-01' 
   AND t2.orderdate<='2016-12-31' 
   AND t1.clientid not in (select clientid from  
                          orders 
                          where orderdate>='2016-01-01'  AND  orderdate<='2016-12-31'  )
```

you  are using group by without aggreation function ( eventually you should use distinct with explict column name )

Comment: so if I use "WHERE t1.clientid NOT IN" presumably that means I can also use "WHERE t1.clientid IN" to replace "JOIN WHERE t2.orderdate>='2015-01-01'" etc ?

Comment: so if I use "WHERE t1.clientid NOT IN" presumably that means I can also use "WHERE t1.clientid IN" to replace "JOIN WHERE t2.orderdate>='2015-01-01'" etc ?
I'll give that a try
Many thanks !

Comment: @Hscott   . i don't understant cleary you comment  .. my answer  mean that from your query you could  discard the clientid in 2016 ..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using NOT IN to filter clients with orders in 2016. I would also use the YEAR function:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM clients AS t1 
  INNER JOIN orders AS t2 
    ON t2.clientid=t1.clientid 
WHERE YEAR(t2.orderdate)=2015
  AND t1.clientid NOT IN (
    SELECT clientid FROM orders sub
    WHERE YEAR(sub.orderdate)=2016
  )
```

Comment: ok thanks to you both I've got it working. I had never seen the YEAR() function before. :)

Comment: There are many date/time functions. You can check them here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html